# From square coordinates to CSS matrix3d()

Tags: javascript, css, math, trigonometry

I'm stuck on a problem :

**Let's consider a square on a surface that is moving (in a video)**. *So remember it's not always a plane surface, it can be skewed, rotated, etc.*

Right now, **I'm detecting it with Aruco JS and getting the coordinates (x,y) of its 4 corners**. I'm pretty sure that, starting with this coordinates, I can render the transformation using `transform: matrix3d();`.

The thing is : I have about 0 knowledge in maths stuff and especially trigonometry. And I really would learn / understand that.

**To sum up : With the coordinates of the corners of a square in real time, how can I apply the transformation to another element using `CSS transform` property ?**

Here's some things I've done so far (this code is executed inside a window.requestAnimationFrame) :

```
  console.log('rotation : ', rotation[0], rotation[1], rotation[2]);
  console.log('translation : ', translation);
  var dimensions = {
    width: lineDistance(corners[0], corners[1]),
    height: lineDistance(corners[0], corners[3])
  }, center = {
    x: corners[0].x + (corners[1].x - corners[0].x)/2,
    y: corners[0].y + (corners[3].y - corners[0].y)/2
  }, rotateAngle = angle(corners[0].x, corners[0].y, corners[1].x, corners[1].y),
    rotateXangle = parseInt(rotation[1][2]);

    img.style.top = corners[0].y;
    img.style.left = corners[0].x;

  img.style.width = dimensions.width;
  img.style.height = dimensions.height;
  img.style.transform = 'rotate('+rotateAngle+'deg) rotateX('+Math.asin(-rotateXangle)+'deg) rotateY('+-Math.atan2(rotation[0][2], rotation[2][2])+'deg) rotateZ('+Math.atan2(rotation[1][0], rotation[1][1])+'deg)';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of this question has been asked on Math Stack Exchange, titled [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/35416). My answer there should serve your needs as well. Plus the better math type setting there will make things easier to read.

Comment: This definitly answer the question. Thank you really much :)